# How to call the new data in JSON file for javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve the data for use again, how to use it?

example script

```js
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

function deleteData() {
    const newData = data
    for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
        if (index === 1) {
            delete newData.a
        }
    }
}
deleteData()
console.log("old data: "+ data)
console.log("new data: "+ newData)
```

expected 
`old data: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`
`new data: { b: 2, c: 3 }`

Comment: I am very confused as to what you are trying to achieve. You're just trying to delete the first element of the object?

Comment: Define newData outside the function. or return the newData from function.

Comment: In your code you are deleting an element only, why are you looping then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Object.assign` or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
const newData = Object.assign({}, data)    // or {...data}

function deleteData() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
        if (index === 1) {
            delete newData.a
        }
    }
}
deleteData()
console.log("old data: ", data)
console.log("new data: ", newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
function deleteData() {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, data)
    for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
        if (index === 1) {
            delete newData.a
        }
    }
    console.log("new data: ", newData)
}
deleteData()
console.log("old data: ", data)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. I'm not sure if you are trying to delete multiple elements from the object or if you are just trying to delete one. If you are only deleting one, you don't need the `for` loop. Just delete it directly.
2. The `const` keyword declares a variable inside the nearest block scope. In your case, that is the `deleteData` function. You need to either declare it as a `let` outside of the function or as a `var` inside, or return it from the function.
3. When you are deleting the item, the object is not a new object, but a reference to the old object. Therefore, both are being modified. To prevent this, copy the object into a new object and modify that. To do this, use `Object.assign`, or simply use the spread operator.

The best way to do this is like this:

```
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

function deleteData(oldData) {
    const updated = {...oldData};
    delete updated.a;
    return updated;
}
const newData = deleteData(data);
console.log("old data: "+ data)
console.log("new data: "+ newData)
```

Some reference reading: [Scope in Javascript](https://javascript.info/closure), [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).